# Blank Screen after Start

Tags: installation, boot, wubi

I just recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 from a CD, it all worked out well and all.

But whenever I start Ubuntu, after display the loading screen with the 5 dots, it turns black and I needed to reboot it.

I'm pretty new to this, but any advice?

I have a Toshiba C655-S5049 dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 with an Intel GMA 4500M graphics card. I think I have to edit the command line, but I'm not sure how or if I'm right.

Comment: Are you running dual monitors?

Comment: No, I am not running dual monitors.

Comment: Not sure why its doing it but you may be able to work around it by trying this. When your pretty sure it is done booting, try hitting `ctrl+alt+f1` to get to a commandline, then try running `startx`

Comment: Try adding `nosplash` as a parameter to your startup line.